# Should an article follow “some sort of” when a singular noun is used?

Tags: articles, prepositional-phrases, zero-article

I was wondering what the rules are when it comes to using articles with the phrase *some sort of*, and specifically in this sentence:

> They’re treating me like I’m some sort of **a** star.
>
> They’re treating me like I’m some sort of star.

To me it sounds better with *a*, but I’m not a native speaker, so I don’t know. Feel free to suggest alternative ways to say the same thing.

Comment: When a **star** means a *celebrity*, it is a common/regular noun and an article is required.

Comment: I've heard it used both ways, but [common usage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YxWTxdzcss) suggests that the article is *not* required. I'd say 'some sort of' means 'a type of'; therefore a further 'a' would be redundant.  Compare with "I'm no expert, but..."

Comment: One alternative is "They're putting me on a pedestal."

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [the BBC Learning English page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv310.shtml) *(archived)*

> sort of (a) / kind of (a) / type of (a)

Sort of / kind of / type of are usually followed by an uncountable noun or a singular countable noun **with no article,** but a / an is sometimes retained in **an informal style:**

> What sort of (a) / kind of (a) / type of (a) dance is that?

Well, it’s a sort of jig or reel, danced to very fast time. I don’t know exactly what it is because there are several types of jigs – single jigs, double jigs, slip jigs and hop jigs.

Note that when the indefinite article is retained, it sometimes has a derogatory meaning:

> What kind of a DVD player is that? You don’t seriously expect me to listen to electronic music with no surround sound, do you?

Comment: I'll second that putting in the indefinite article is often derogatory. "What kind of dance is that?" sounds like a genuine question, whereas "What kind of a dance is that?" sounds like a rhetorical question, implying that it's not a proper/real/acceptable dance.